# Winrar CommandLine & Powershell : Exclude Full Directory Path Structure

Tags: powershell, archive, winrar

Suppose I have a directory structure like

```
C:\Users\Desktop\abc\d
```

I want to rar archive the abc folder so that the structure of rar is:

```
abc\d
```

When I try using powershell to archive, winrar replicates the full path inside the archive, like:

```
\Users\Desktop\abc\d
```

I dont want the full path to be created inside the archive
Here's the script:
https://gist.github.com/saurabhwahile/50f1091fb29c2bb327b7

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could jump to root dir of where your archive is ie `cd C:\Users\Desktop` then run your winrar command against `abc\d`. Also paste your code here - or at least the relevant bits - rather than link to an outside source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the command line:

```
Rar.exe a -r -ep1 Test.rar "C:\Users\Desktop\abc"
```

`Rar.exe` is the console version of **WinRAR** stored in same directory as `WinRAR.exe`. You can use this command line also with `WinRAR.exe` if you want to see the compression process in a graphic window.

`a` is the command and means *add files to archive*.

`-r` is a switch to recursively add all files and subdirectories including empty subdirectories to the archive.

`-ep1` is another switch which results in execluding base directory.

For this command line the base directory is "C:\Users\Desktop\" and therefore the created archive `Test.rar` contains only `abc` and all files and subdirectories in directory `abc` which is what you want.

One more hint: Using the command line

```
Rar.exe a -r -ep1 Test.rar "C:\Users\Desktop\abc\"
```

results in adding all files and subdirectories of directory `abc` to the archive, but without directory name `abc` being also stored in the archive. The backslash at end makes this difference.

In other words: On using switch `-ep1` everything up to last backslash in file/directory specification is not added to the archive.

For more information about available switches see the text file **Rar.txt** in the program files directory of **WinRAR**.